# WSO2 APIM connecting to backend service secured with QWAC certificate

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am implementing an API gateway for a backend service which requires QWAC certificate.
I followed the instructions at: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/administer/product-security/mutual-ssl-between-api-gateway-and-backend/ and imported the public key to client keystore in WSO APIM.

When I try to reach the endpoint in question I am getting the following error response:
`{"errorCode":"bad_request","errorText":"400 - {\"status\":\"INVALID\",\"errorCode\":\"unspecified_error\",\"errorText\":\"Mapping error\"}"}`, which seems to be coming from the 
backend service.

Here is the output from wso2carbon wire logs:

```
2  Message direction=IN  Server name=localhost  Timestamp=1587116916556  Service name=__SynapseService  Operation Name=mediate
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:36,823] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "GET /api/slsp/sandbox/v1/psd2-ais/v1/accounts HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:36,890] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Authorization: ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInRva2VuIiwKICAibmFtZSI6ICJTTFNQIGNsaWVudDEiLAogICJzZXNzaW9uVVVJRCI6ICIyMzI1YzFkMS01ZTMwLTQ2NGQtOGM0Ni1kYzc5Y2E2NTkzMDAiLAogICJzY29wZXMiOiBbXSwKICAiY29uc2VudCI6IFsKICAgIHsKICAgICAgImlkIjogIjExMTExIiwKICAgICAgImNvbnRlbnQiOiAibm9uZSIKICAgIH0KICBdLAogICJsaW1pdHMiOiB7CiAgICAiYWNjZXNzU2Vjb25kcyI6IDM2MDAsCiAgICAicmVmcmVzaFNlY29uZHMiOiA3Nzc2MDAwCiAgfSwKICAiYWNjZXNzVHlwZSI6ICJudWxsIiwKICAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDIwLTA0LTE3VDA5OjUxOjI2LjQ1MVoiCn0=[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:36,954] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "activityID: 490325399145411914682[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,017] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "web-api-key: b5830b00-772f-4e94-8a4a-be370d4e5481[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,082] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,145] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Host: webapi.developers.erstegroup.com[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,208] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,273] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,336] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,642] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "HTTP/1.1 400 [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,706] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 09:48:37 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,771] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Server: Apache[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,835] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,900] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "cz-transactionId: 197173439577254[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:37,966] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:38,031] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Length: 140[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:38,095] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Set-Cookie: 48f65e4d401373b3b03cb2a02b953e21=425c12b91ee874d67b6799357c467562; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:38,158] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:38,221] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2020-04-17 11:48:38,286] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "{"errorCode":"bad_request","errorText":"400 - {\"status\":\"INVALID\",\"errorCode\":\"unspecified_error\",\"errorText\":\"Mapping error\"}"}"
```

I have tried to reach the same service with Postman, after I imported the client certificate in postman , the service was responding without errors.

So it looks like the isssue is not with the certificate itself, as the SSL connection was established with the backend server, but what could have gone wrong? (When the OAuth2.0 token expires I get the following error "OAUTH2 failed to TOKEN_INFO with response: {\\"active\\":false}", which is the same as what I get with Postman.)

Here is the swagger spec from WSO2 APIM:

```
paths: 
    /accounts: 
      get: 
        parameters: 
          - 
            name: "withBalance"
            in: "query"
            required: false
            style: "form"
            explode: true
            schema: 
              type: "string"
          - 
            name: "web-api-key"
            in: "query"
            required: true
            style: "form"
            explode: true
            schema: 
              type: "string"
          - 
            name: "access_token"
            in: "query"
            required: true
            style: "form"
            explode: true
            schema: 
              type: "string"
        responses: 
          200: 
            description: "ok"
        security: 
          - 
            default: []
        x-auth-type: "None"
        x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
  components: 
    securitySchemes: 
      default: 
        type: "oauth2"
        flows: 
          implicit: 
            authorizationUrl: "https://test.com"
            scopes: {}
  x-wso2-auth-header: "Authorization"
  x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
  x-wso2-cors: 
    corsConfigurationEnabled: false
    accessControlAllowOrigins: 
      - "*"
    accessControlAllowCredentials: false
    accessControlAllowHeaders: 
      - "authorization"
      - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      - "Content-Type"
      - "SOAPAction"
    accessControlAllowMethods: 
      - "GET"
      - "PUT"
      - "POST"
      - "DELETE"
      - "PATCH"
      - "OPTIONS"
  x-wso2-sandbox-endpoints: 
    urls: 
      - "https://webapi.developers.erstegroup.com/api/slsp/sandbox/v1/psd2-ais/v1"
    type: "http"
  x-wso2-basePath: "/slsp_ais/1.0"
  x-wso2-transports: 
    - "http"
```

I tried to pass the 2 mandatory parameters in HTTP headers as well, but I get the same results:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8280/slsp_ais/1.0/accounts" -H "accept: application/json" -H "web-api-key: b5830b00-772f-4e94-8a4a-be370d4e5481" -H "Authorization: Bearer ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInRva2VuIiwKICAibmFtZSI6ICJTTFNQIGNsaWVudDEiLAogICJzZXNzaW9uVVVJRCI6ICIyMzI1YzFkMS01ZTMwLTQ2NGQtOGM0Ni1kYzc5Y2E2NTkzMDAiLAogICJzY29wZXMiOiBbXSwKICAiY29uc2VudCI6IFsKICAgIHsKICAgICAgImlkIjogIjExMTExIiwKICAgICAgImNvbnRlbnQiOiAibm9uZSIKICAgIH0KICBdLAogICJsaW1pdHMiOiB7CiAgICAiYWNjZXNzU2Vjb25kcyI6IDM2MDAsCiAgICAicmVmcmVzaFNlY29uZHMiOiA3Nzc2MDAwCiAgfSwKICAiYWNjZXNzVHlwZSI6ICJudWxsIiwKICAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDIwLTA0LTE3VDA5OjUxOjI2LjQ1MVoiCn0=" -H  "apikey: eyJ4NXQiOiJaalJtWVRNd05USmpPV1U1TW1Jek1qZ3pOREkzWTJJeU1tSXlZMkV6TWpkaFpqVmlNamMwWmc9PSIsImtpZCI6ImdhdGV3YXlfY2VydGlmaWNhdGVfYWxpYXMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.QJ8-ODdRueTtDKDfWYVFeI3I6YJGfCtRGIg64nGdewQP9jW8KzyFLmkt14i7OGXkKpA4e2Yowa9lidxN0qrdRmUjJLKpZmBOn6TjN5auE8TcvxyeSlOigK0N-J-eLB6DuHnqg6Rf918d2oJS2bJBmqbzqs0BPMuEj5Y9ImS7F1CdMcRaDTOYt6G-GxmwpScU4dlxOrxZGu8uD5Nnz2SHikXSqGcrF-KLmNUFJuFKTitEMEaHz8N9M-MYsTDlOnvu0BeEFiW60NRCPumzCOzs5wL7dMTcCXOGd40-OKcUkS2KpH-YEh7cl0ALz9wi0vgFRqN0V2CAndbCUwppmkzo9w=="
{"errorCode":"bad_request","errorText":"400 - {\"status\":\"INVALID\",\"errorCode\":\"unspecified_error\",\"errorText\":\"Mapping error\"}"}
```

I also intercepted the working Postman request via Burp:

```
GET /api/slsp/sandbox/v1/psd2-ais/v1/accounts?web-api-key=b5830b00-772f-4e94-8a4a-be370d4e5481&access_token=ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInRva2VuIiwKICAibmFtZSI6ICJTTFNQIGNsaWVudDEiLAogICJzZXNzaW9uVVVJRCI6ICIyMzI1YzFkMS01ZTMwLTQ2NGQtOGM0Ni1kYzc5Y2E2NTkzMDAiLAogICJzY29wZXMiOiBbXSwKICAiY29uc2VudCI6IFsKICAgIHsKICAgICAgImlkIjogIjExMTExIiwKICAgICAgImNvbnRlbnQiOiAibm9uZSIKICAgIH0KICBdLAogICJsaW1pdHMiOiB7CiAgICAiYWNjZXNzU2Vjb25kcyI6IDM2MDAsCiAgICAicmVmcmVzaFNlY29uZHMiOiA3Nzc2MDAwCiAgfSwKICAiYWNjZXNzVHlwZSI6ICJudWxsIiwKICAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDIwLTA0LTE3VDA5OjUxOjI2LjQ1MVoiCn0= HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b925ae09-0b5b-440f-a1e9-98bc5f79b043
Host: webapi.developers.erstegroup.com:443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
```

Here is the whole thing via Postman console:

```
GET /api/slsp/sandbox/v1/psd2-ais/v1/accounts?web-api-key=b5830b00-772f-4e94-8a4a-be370d4e5481&access_token=ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInRva2VuIiwKICAibmFtZSI6ICJTTFNQIGNsaWVudDEiLAogICJzZXNzaW9uVVVJRCI6ICI4MWJlZDMwMS1lMGFkLTQwMzAtODMxMC0wNThmZDViYWIyMDkiLAogICJzY29wZXMiOiBbXSwKICAiY29uc2VudCI6IFsKICAgIHsKICAgICAgImlkIjogIjExMTExIiwKICAgICAgImNvbnRlbnQiOiAibm9uZSIKICAgIH0KICBdLAogICJsaW1pdHMiOiB7CiAgICAiYWNjZXNzU2Vjb25kcyI6IDM2MDAsCiAgICAicmVmcmVzaFNlY29uZHMiOiA3Nzc2MDAwCiAgfSwKICAiYWNjZXNzVHlwZSI6ICJudWxsIiwKICAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDIwLTA0LTE3VDExOjU0OjQ5LjA4OFoiCn0%3D HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: fc30b165-7571-4efe-96fe-e23b1cf1c20e
Host: webapi.developers.erstegroup.com:443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 10:55:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
accept: */*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
correlation-id: 6b27116c-15e6-4410-8ff7-87afd9bbd92b
forwarded: for=10.198.136.200;host=webapi.prod.eapihub.microp.cs.eb.lan.at;proto=https;proto-version=
ip-address: 178.41.84.88
origin-transaction-id: 185078296373260
postman-token: fc30b165-7571-4efe-96fe-e23b1cf1c20e
TPP-QWAC-Body: 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
transaction-id: 185078296373260
web-api-correlation-id: 6b27116c-15e6-4410-8ff7-87afd9bbd92b
web-api-transaction-id: 185078296373260
x-forwarded-for: 178.41.84.88, 178.41.84.88
x-forwarded-host: webapi.prod.eapihub.microp.cs.eb.lan.at
x-forwarded-port: 443
x-forwarded-proto: https
x-forwarded-server: webapi.developers.erstegroup.com
X-Traits: TPP_ONLY;PSD2_QWAC;DELEGATE_QSEAL_VALIDATION
x-webapi-client-ip: 178.41.84.88
x-webapi-message-id: 185078296373260
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: br
Content-Length: 276
Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"accounts":[{"resourceId":"CCA4F9863D686D04","iban":"SK5409000000005037706253","currency":"EUR","name":"Mag. A. M. Tester","cashAccountType":"CACC","status":"enabled","bic":"GIBASKBX","_links":{"detail":{"href":"/v1/accounts/CCA4F9863D686D04"},"balances":{"href":"/v1/accounts/CCA4F9863D686D04/balances"},"transactions":{"href":"/v1/psd2-ais/v1/transactions"}}},{"resourceId":"AF500F1000071A0A0","iban":"SK0209000000005037645497","currency":"USD","name":"Adam Tester","cashAccountType":"CACC","status":"enabled","bic":"GIBASKBX","_links":{"balances":{"href":"/v1/accounts/AF500F1000071A0A0/balances"},"transactions":{"href":"/v1/accounts/AF500F1000071A0A0/transactions"}}}]}
```

I would appreciate any feedback. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As you have mentioned the connection with the backend has been successful. But something else has been gone wrong. You will need more error details from the backend party.

Comment: Can I set a proxy for the WSO2 API gateway to intercept the outgoing requests?

Comment: what kind of a proxy?

Comment: HTTP proxy to capture application traffic between Api gateway and backend service. I am thinking about Postman interceptor.

Comment: I forgot to mention in Postman I imported both the public certificate and the private key. In WSO2 APIM I imported the public certificate only. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the keystore in WSO2-AM side you need to import the private key, not just the certifiate

Refer to the sample at https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/administer/product-security/mutual-ssl-between-api-gateway-and-backend/

```
<!-- For Mutual SSL Handshake configure both trust store and key store-->  
    <profile>
        <servers>10.100.5.130:9444</servers>
        <TrustStore>
        <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
        </Location>
        <Type>JKS</Type>
    <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
        </TrustStore>
    <KeyStore>
        <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
        <Type>JKS</Type>
        <Password>xxxxxx</Password>
        <KeyPassword>xxxxxx</KeyPassword>
    </KeyStore>
</profile>
</parameter>
```

In the keystore file `repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks` you need to have private key of your client certificate.